# extend an object returned by a static method in java

Tags: java, oop, static, subclass, superclass

I have the following problem.

I have a static method of a library class (that I cannot change) like this:

```
Loader.loadModel()
```

it returns an object of type Model.

I have also created a subclass of Model called ExtendedModel that adds to Model some methods and some fields.

I cannot do:

```
ExtendedModel m = Loader.loadModel() //compiler error
ExtendedModel m = (ExtendedModel) Loader.loadModel() //ClassCastException at runtime
```

because in Java you cannot assign a object of a super class to a sub class.

However, I was wondering: which is the best way in which I could add methods and fields to a object returned by Loader.loadModel()

Comment: What is the actual type `Loader.loadModel()` return? And you need to investigate this method to see if you can change its default behavior. For example, does it get the implementation class via properties?

Comment: superclass can be assigned to subclass in specific cases. See my answer below.

Comment: You can do this in general with all classes and objects extending from each other using the request API (as stated in my answer).

Comment: The actual type returned by Loader.loadModel() is Model and I cannot change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you have added a new class, you do not have a new instance of that class. In order to be able to use the additional methods and fields of a model, you need to have an instance of `ExtendedModel`; the `Loader.loadModel()` returns an instance of the "regular" `Model`, causing the problem.

To extend functionality of an object you need to write a wrapper class. A wrapper typically takes an object of the "base" class, delegates the base functionality to it, and adds some methods/variables of its own:

```
public class ExtendedModel : Model {
    private final Model wrapped;
    public ExtendedModel(Model model) { wrapped = model; }
    private int addedField = 123;
    // Methods of the Model that you did not change simply forward the calls:
    public void doSomething() { wrapped.doSomething(); }
    public int calculateSomething() { return wrapped.calculateSomething(); }
    // Extended methods do whatever you need them to do:
    public int getAddedField() {return addedField;}
    public void increment() {addedField++;}
}
```

Now you can create an instance of `ExtendedModel` like this:

```
ExtendedModel m = new ExtendedModel(Loader.loadModel());
```

Answer (score 2):

What you **could** do is working with the Java Reflect API. This provides the most easy implementation, but might not be as fast as other solutions.

What you basically have to do is to pass all the data from Model to ExtendedModel and to let ExtendedModel of course extend Model.

My "Model" class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
    Model model = new Model(1);
    ExtendedModel extended = model.get(ExtendedModel.class);
    extended.setA2("Hello World");
    System.out.println(extended.getA1());
    System.out.println(extended.getA2());
}

private int a1;

public Model() {}
public Model(int a1) {
    this.a1 = a1;
}

public void setA1(int a1) {
    this.a1 = a1;
}

public int getA1() {
    return this.a1;
}

/**
 * This method will transform the current object into an ExtendedModel.
 * @throws SecurityException 
 * @throws NoSuchMethodException 
 * @throws InvocationTargetException 
 * @throws IllegalArgumentException 
 * @throws IllegalAccessException 
 * @throws InstantiationException 
 */
public <T> T get(Class<? extends T> classType) throws InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException, IllegalArgumentException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, SecurityException {
    T object = classType.getConstructor().newInstance();

    // pass all the data via setters
    for (Field field : this.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
        String methodName = "set"+StringUtil.ucfirst(field.getName()); // uppercase first!
        classType.getMethod(methodName, field.getType()).invoke(object, field.get(this));
    }

    // return object
    return object;
}
```

My "ExtendedModel" class:

```
public class ExtendedModel extends Model {

    private String a2;

    public ExtendedModel() {}

    public String getA2() {
        return this.a2;
    }

    public void setA2(String a2) {
        this.a2 = a2;
    }

}
```

You could, of course, also use getters instead of directly accessing the properties. This would help you in using the solution with other classes/objects as well easily. The only important things are:

1. Declare a default constructor (with no or a set and known number of parameters).
2. Copy all the data from "Model" to "ExtendedModel" or whatever class you want to extend.

Answer (score 0):

**You can't**.

This is how object oriented programming works. If you want to add any additional functionality, **write a helperclass containing static methods** which accept a `Model` and returns some desired value, e.g. an `int`, `double`, ...

Answer (score 0):

you can't, but what you can do is using the [adapter pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) which is simply another class that will have a field with type of the original object, then you can perform your operations on that object.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Your solution will always need a crude approach.

Let "Loader.loadModel()" return instance of "ExtendedModel" but return object will be set to reference of Model. Something like this:

```
Model m = Loader.loadModel();
```

Now your casting will work, as shown below.

```
ExtendedModel mx = (ExtendedModel) m;
```

This is something similar to what use to happen before generics. Downcasting is allowed in specific cases like i have shown above.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change Loader.loadModel() to make it returns an instance of "ExtendedModel"